# how can I highlight just one item from the ls output

Tags: unix, colors, ls

real beginner in Unix commands so not sure if the following is actually possible but here goes.
Is it possible to highlight just one item in a ls output?

I.e.: in a directory I use the following

```
ls -l --color=auto
```

this lists 4 items in green

```
file1.xls
file2.xls
file3.xls
file4.xls
```

But I want to highlight a specific item, in this case file2.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ls` program will not do this for you.  But you could filter the results from `ls` through a custom script which modifies the text to highlight just one item.  It would be simpler if no color was originally given; then you could match on the given filename (for example as the pattern in an awk script, or in a sed script) and modify just that one item, adding colors.

That is, certainly it is possible.  Writing a sample script is a different question.

How you approach the problem depends on what you *want* from the output.  If that is (literally) the output from `ls` with a single filename in color, then a script would be the normal approach.  You could use `grep` as suggested in the other answer, which raises a few issues:

- commenting on `ls -l --color=auto` makes it sound as if you are using GNU ls, hence likely using Linux.  An appropriate tag for the question would be *linux* rather than *unix*.  If you ask for *unix*, the answers should differ.
- supposing that you are using Linux.  Then likely you have GNU grep, which can do colors.  That would let you do something like this:

  `ls -l | grep --color=always file2 |less -R`
- however, there is a known bug in GNU grep's use of color (see xterm FAQ *["grep --color" does not show the right output](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#grep_colors)*).
- using grep like this shows only the matching lines.  For `ls` that might be a good choice.  For matches in a manual page -- definitely not.

Alternatively, `less` (which is found more often on Unix systems than GNU grep) also can highlight matches (not in color) and would show the file you are looking for in context.  You could do this:

```
ls -l | less -p file2
```

(Both `grep` and `less` use *patterns* aka *regular expressions*, but I left the example simple — read the documentation to learn more).

Answer (score 0):

If you're a beginner I would strongly suggest you learn the `grep` command if you want to filter results - A Unix users best friend (mine anyway)

Use `grep` to only display the list items you want to see...

```
ls- l | grep "file2"
```

NOTE: This is no different to typing `ls -l file2` by the way but your pattern could be expanded based on what you actually want displayed on the screen.

So if you had a directory full of files ".txt", ".xls", ".doc" and you wanted to only see ".doc" with the word "work" in the name (work1.doc) you could write:

```
ls -ls | grep "work" | grep "txt"
```

This would list work1.txt, work2.txt, work3.txt and so on.

This is a very basic example but I use grep extensively whilst in the unix shell and would advise using this to filter all results instead of colours.

A little side note using grep -v will show you everything but the pattern you give it

`ls -l | grep -v ".txt"` will show everything BUT .txt files.